# Some values are being skipped when copying value from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-sheets

I have an array of item codes used to match against a column of item codes so if it finds the matching cell, it will copy the price from the price array to the price column. Here's the code:

```
for (z = 3; z < codearray.length; z++) {
    for (w = 0; w < orderingValue.length; w++) {
        if (parseInt(orderingValue[w][codecol]) == parseInt(codearray[0])) {
            copyrow = w + 1;
            orderingss.getRange(copyrow, salescol).setValue(pricearray[0]);
            codearray.shift();
            pricearray.shift();
        }
    }
}
```

At first I thought the code works, but I noticed for some reason some of the item codes were skipped. I did confirm the codes and the price value do exist in the arrays so I'm not sure what would cause the skip.

Edit: I may have found the real cause. I noticed it stops copying when it finds a item code in the codearray that does not match. Once I fixed the item code, all went through fine. Is there a way to have the loop continue or skip the item code if it does not find a match?

Comment: What's `codecol`? I see it being used but you never define it anywhere.

Comment: I apologize, the codecol is the column number where the item codes that is being matched against resides.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you remove items in the array while looping .

I mean the following line

```
codearray.shift();
```

You can workaround this by the solution as stated below

```
var copiedCodeArray = codearray.slice();
for(z = 3;z<copiedCodeArray.length;z++){
  // paste the rest of the code here
```

Comment: I think I found the cause but I'm not sure how to fix it. When I sort the item code numerically before putting into an array, everything copies through. From what I understand this means the loop isn't checking the entire orderingValue from the beginning every time?

Comment: If you use shift() (or any other method that removes elements from an array) withing a loop, the element will be removed, so for example the when removing the element at index 1, the element at position 2 will shift to left, so its index will be 1 now and your loop won't cover it, as the current iterating number would be 2.